# What is an ECT team?

Tags: meaning, terminology, acronyms

It's a quote from the drama *Manifest*

> -They've got an **ECT team** on site. They're canvassing the neighborhood.
>
> -They'll focus on the family first. Monitor the situation and report back.

There was a little boyo got missing and the police sent an **ECT team** to look around the neighborhood.

I checked ECT online and got the answer *Electroconvulsive therapy* ... Is that the meaning here? Cause I don't think it's some kind of medical team here.

Comment: We say "who *went* missing" not "who got missing".

Comment: This kind of question would be better to ask on [Movies & TV SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to look up *Manifest*; the Wikipedia entry indicates that it takes place in and around New York City.

I am a non-enforcement employee of the NYPD. ***ECT*** is an abbreviation for ***Evidence Collection Team***; there is a useful summary of the ECT’s role in the [Wikipedia entry on NYPD Organization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organization_of_the_New_York_City_Police_Department#Evidence_Collection_Teams) (and the rest of the Wikipedia entry is useful for understanding the structure of the Department in most NYC-based ‘cop shows’).